# how to add object collection List to another class object list

Tags: java, object, arraylist, collections, stream

The Stream in line three returns Collection(List) of . However, I am unable to store them directly in veggiesList. Can you help me with the best option

```
List<VeggieDetails> veggiesList = new ArrayList<>();
veggiesWebelementlist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table//td[1]"));
veggiesList =veggiesWebelementlist.stream().map(e->getVeggieRow(e)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

private static Object getVeggieRow(WebElement e) {

```
    return new VeggieDetails(e.getText(), e.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::td[1]")).getText(),
            e.findElement(By.xpath("following-sibling::td[2]")).getText());
}
```

Comment: Consider that you have to map the object so it would fit in the destination list and use this code :     listDest.addAll(listSource);

Comment: Yes, @arashyousefi. check the code return the specific object in the map.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. I changed the return type to the expected Class(VeggieDetails) in the map method. Thanks.